# Using autofilter and select yesterday's date

Tags: excel, vba

I am interested in filtering my data to the previous business day date.

Currently, I have the following:

```
Selection.AutoFilter ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$L$810").AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:= _xlFilterValues Criteria2:=Array(2, "4/24/2021")
```

1. How should I change the date so that the data will always filter to the previous business day? or filter to the latest available date ( the data I receive for a given day is for the previous day and the previous dates are exhaustive- that's why I always have to select the previous date manually)
2. Also, I would like to learn how to change it to the previous day(not a business day) as well.

Many thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the DateAdd function (Google it).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple function to return the previous business date. Note that it only handles weekends. Holidays are much more complicated to handle.

```
Function GetPreviousBusinessDay(ByVal dt As Date) As Date

    Select Case Weekday(dt)
        
        Case vbMonday
            GetPreviousBusinessDay = dt - 3
        
        Case vbSunday
            GetPreviousBusinessDay = dt - 2
        
        Case Else
            GetPreviousBusinessDay = dt - 1
    
    End Select
    
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You're two questions needs two different VBA functions. To make it more readable, I'll use a string variable as Filter criteria for dates needs to be a string.

```
Selection.AutoFilter

dim PreviousDate as string

'If you want the previous day use this :
PreviousDate = Format(CDate(date()-1), "mm/dd/yyyy")

'If you want previous working day us this one :
PreviousDate = Format(CDate(Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Date(), -1)), "mm/dd/yyyy")

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$L$810").AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues Criteria2:=Array(2, PreviousDate)
```

That's it

Comment: thanks for the tips @SomeDude - but I got the following error: Run-Time error "1004" AutoFilter Method of Range class failed- what did i do wrong here?

     `Selection.AutoFilter

Dim PreviousDate As String
PreviousDate=CStr(CDate(Date()-1))
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$L$810").AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues Criteria2:=Array(2, PreviousDate)`

Comment: I guess this have to do with the date format. In my initial function it was "dd/mm/yyyy" and it must be "mm/dd/yyyy".
I modified my code and now everything must be fine (replaced CStr() functions by Format() functions.

Comment: @Sarah T Any news ?